# $m_{1},\ldots,m_{k}$ relatively prime,$M=max\{m_{1},...,m_{k}\}$ then product M consecutive numbers is divisible for $m_{1}\times\ldots\times m_{k}$

Tags: number-theory

How would you prove that for $m_{1},\ldots,m_{k}$ relatively prime and $M=max\{m_{1},...,m_{k}\}$  then product of $M$ consecutive numbers is divisible for $m_{1}\times\ldots\times m_{k}$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you say "divisible for" do you mean "divisible by"?  Are you trying to show $m_{1} \times \dots \times m_{k}$ will divide the product of $M$ consecutive numbers?

Comment: @user46944 yes, "divisible by"

Comment: What do you mean by "relatively prime" for more than two integers?  Do you consider $\left\{2,3,4\right\}$ as a set of relatively prime numbers?  If not, you should perhaps state that the $m_i$'s are ***pairwise relatively prime***.

Comment: My guess is for more than two numbers it means "pairwise coprime".

Comment: In fact, if the $m_i$'s are pairwise distinct positive integers, then it already holds that the product of $M$ consecutive integers is divisible by $\prod_{i=1}^k\,m_i$, since this product must necessarily divide $M!$.

Comment: Example: 2,3,5,7 and $M=max\{2,3,5,7\}=7$ then there are 7 numbers that multiplied are divisible for 2*3*5*7

Answer (score 1):

Since the $m_k$ are pairwise coprime, one only need show the product is divisible by each $m_k$ individually. But there are at least $m_k$ consecutive numbers so one of them is divisible by $m_k.$